# Block cookies from being stored in browser

Tags: javascript, google-chrome, google-chrome-extension

I'm trying to create an extension that will have "privacy mode" as an option. When "Privacy Mode" is on, no cookies will be collected by Chrome. I need to do this while **not** browsing in Incognito mode. Is this possible? In chrome.cookies, if I didn't set expirationDate will the prevent Chrome from storing any cookies?

Comment: The documentation says "If omitted, the cookie becomes a session cookie." Alternatively, you can intercept all requests using chrome.webRequest.onHeadersReceived API and remove `Expires` from the `Set-Cookie` header.